# Replacing the catch-all feature of g-suite gmail with a whitelist

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I use about 100-150 email addresses using the catch-all feature of gmail in g-suite.

When I sign up for a new service I make up an email address for that service so they don't have my real email address.

Is there a way to switch from a catch-all to a whitelist of names? Google does a great job of catching the spam but still I'd like to consider being able to put emails on a whitelist, hopefully one that is easy to edit so if I'm signing up to a new service from a phone I can easily add the new address to the whitelist.

Note that currently using the catch-all feature I am also able to send from and reply from those email addresses. In other words, someone sends to `xyz@mydomain.com`, gmail's catch all feature makes that email show in my main email account `me@mydomain.com`. If I click `reply` the reply defaults to being from `xyz@mydomain.com`. I don't want to lose that feature.

BTW: [catch-all is being deprecated](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33962) so I'm looking for a solution that works with the new ways of doing things, not the catch-all way.